# how to globally override a blueprint action in sails 1.0

Tags: sails.js

I might be wrong but overriding a blueprint action appears to be gone in sails 1.0.
what I'm trying to do is for the output of find to be:

```
{
  "data": [...],
  "meta": {
    "count": 10,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it looks to have been removed from 1.0. https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-custom-blueprints provides a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is true for V0.12: If you want to call the same action for "find" you can create your own find.js file in **/api/blueprints**. This globally overrides the action "find", provided that your controllers do not have any custom "find" methods themselves.

For the version 1.0, the documentation suggests this [link](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/upgrading/To1.0.md#replacing-custom-blueprints)

Comment: Are you sure? Afaik, in 1.0 this only appears to be true after installing "sails-hook-custom-blueprints".

Comment: According to this [link](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/blueprint-api/blueprint-api.md), _"To override the default action that all controllers use, create an api/blueprints folder and add files to it with names matching the actions to override (e.g. find.js, findone.js, create.js, etc.). You can take a look at the code for the default actions in the Sails blueprints hook for a head start."_

Comment: @fimdomeio, you are right, on closer inspection of the V1.0 docs, I found this [link](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/upgrading/To1.0.md#replacing-custom-blueprints)_

Comment: For completeness sake the same [page you linked to on the 1.0 branch](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/blueprint-api/blueprint-api.md)